# Content Control Removal - Need solution

Tags: openxml, contentcontrol, wordprocessingml

I need to work on document generation module of out application. I have gone through some of the links and blogs that helped me to go ahead and implement Content Control and Custom XML based document generation.

With this approach, we are able to generate the document with data from XML mapped with content controls. The major concern we have, we do not know how to remove the content control once the XML data is updated.

Scenario:

1. Generated document contains Content control that are visible to user. How to avoid it? We want the code snippet to handle this case
2. Some of the cases, We have used nested content controls. The content controls for particular section or Data is validate against input data XML before document generation. Based on the XML value, some of the sections/values will be removed programatically.

I have gone through the following links with the hope of getting the solution:

http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/formats/f/13/p/750/3578.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/oxmlsdk/thread/2bff522d-8eb8-4d82-a8d6-4e27d9ce57af

I am new to OpenXMl, so appreciate your help at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove content controls while keeping text check http://worddocgenerator.codeplex.com. RemoveContentControlsAndKeepContents method of OpenXmlHelper class does the same.